# Problems with textarea, within a textarea

Tags: html, forms, textarea

I'm making a cms system, where you can edit the web pages that is stored in the database(html) on the website. i'm using textarea to display the html code like this.

```
<textarea><?php echo($pagecontent); ?></textarea>
```

The problem is that, on one of the pages, there's a textarea to, and for some reason it just cuts of the rest of the code after the  starts.

Here's a picture, so you might understand me better: http://i.imgur.com/QueZNEV.png

Been looking around, but i can't seem to find a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your textarea contains characters which have special meaning in HTML (`<`, `&`, etc) but you want them to be treated as data, not as special characters.

Run them through `htmlspecialchars()` before echoing them.

Comment: Could you show me an example, of how i should run them through that?

Comment: This is how my form looks like `<article id="feedback-form">
        <form name="myForm" action="insert_feedback.php" method="post">
              <input type="text" name="firstname" class="input" placeholder="Navn:" value="">
              <input type="email" name="email" class="input" placeholder="Email:" value="">
              <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Besked:" maxlength="120" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
            <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
    </article>`

Comment: And this is the form, that contains that form.`<form name="myForm" action="insert_update.php" method="post">
    <p class="space">You are currently updating <?php echo "<span id='title'>".$pagetitle."</span>" ?></p>
    <p>
      <textarea rows="40" name="pagecontent" id="pagecontent" class="pagecontent" cols="50" rows="5" style="resize:vertical;"><?php echo($pagecontent);?></textarea>
    </p>
    <input id="btn-update" type="submit" value="Opdatere">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo($id) ?>" name="id" />
</form>`